# Eclipse not creating JPA entities from table

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I'm using Eclipse Juno, Hibernate 4.0 and MSSQL 2008.
I've created a database and have just gone through the process "JPA Entities from Tables" in Eclipse. About half of the tables did not get created (even though I selected those table), but the classes were added to persistence.xml.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Do you have a solution?

Comment: I already had this problem, but I just completed the mapping manually (not too much work in my case)

Comment: Are there any exceptions in your Eclipse workspace log (.metadata/.log)?

Comment: I'm getting the exception *org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unable to find JPA entities generation templates in pluginorg.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen* in the eclipse log

Comment: Also getting the exception *org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getImportStatements' in  class org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: cms_page.cms_page_cms_page_FK - mismatched sizes: 0 vs. 1 @ main.java.vm[7,9]*

Answer (score 4):

In my case the database was Oracle XE. So mine is a bit different case but may be helpful to someone.

The best way to find the problem with this is to check the logs of workspace present at $workspace_location/.metadata/.log file. In my case I found that there were 3 problems:

1) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: $MiddlewarePath\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share_11.1.1\adfsharembean.jar (Access is denied)

2) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: $MiddlewarePath\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ldap_11.1.1\jremtool.jar (Access is denied)

3) !MESSAGE Unable to find JPA entities generation templates in pluginorg.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 275] A resource exists with a different case: '/TestJPAProjectFacetsEJB/src/main/java/com/domainname/ejb/TestJPAProjectFacets'.

Hence I did the following:

1) Provided access permission for the jar files
2) While I was generating entities I was giving the package name as com/domainname/ejb/testjpaprojectfacets/model. But I was already having a package com/domainname/ejb/TestJPAProjectFacets hence the error. I then renamed my existing package to all lowercase (com/domainname/ejb/testjpaprojectfacets) and it worked.

Thanks,
Sanjay

Comment: Thanks for the log debugging. In my case the user did not have sufficient permission to access the schema list from syscat

Answer (score 3):

My workaround was to use the JTDS JDBC Driver to connect to SQL Server database instead of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver

Comment: Which version of the JTDS JDBC Driver you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Eclipse DTP bug [282206](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282206). Dali (the Eclipse project that supplies the Entity Generation wizard you are using) depends on the Eclipse DTP project for retrieving from various database servers the necessary meta-data to generate entities. The MS SQL Server "driver" you are using (i.e. the plug-in used by DTP to adapt the MS SQL JDBC driver to the DTP SPI interfaces - by default this plug-in is `org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.sqlserver...` - it is a bit confusing that the DTP developers like to call these plug-ins "drivers"....) has a bug in the meta-data it returns to Dali, preventing Dali from generating entities.

Comment: I'm using the MS SQL driver from the Microsoft website. Can you suggest a driver to try? I was able to generate the entities in Netbeans using the same driver. I can't believe more people haven't experienced this issue.

Comment: Is there any other way to generate the entities in Eclipse? I don't want to have to manually type everything.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion: The "driver" I am talking about is an Eclipse plug-in that adapts a JDBC driver to the Java interfaces defined by DTP. DTP ships with a number of "drivers" for various databases (Sybase, Derby, MySQL, etc.) along with a generic "driver" that attempts to adapt any standard JDBC driver. So this problem is an *Eclipse* problem. Some of these drivers are in much better shape than others, depending on who worked on them over the years. As you can see, the MS SQL bug I referenced is almost 4 years old.... You could comment on the bug and/or contribute a patch....

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too.

My workaround - Created the database in MySQL and generated entities from there. The  generated entity classes work with SQL Server as well. Not faced any other side-effects (so far)